# How to add custom data-* attributes in react-bootstrap component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute

I am using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) for 'atom' level components in my react app and I want to pass HTML5 data-* attributes to those component and even though I do pass them in my react-bootstrap component ( [Button](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/) in my case) they do not show up and when I inspect them and hence I am not able to use them

Now Is there a way to do that? I have went through their [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) but there is no clue as to how to do that?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Nenotlep: Well Not really! The extra information I wanted to keep in custom attribute I appended it in id attribute.

Comment: @HVenom, which version of react-bootstrap do you use. As I see in the latest code they do pass the rest props to the component and hence it would work for most components

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Well! This is weird at the time I posted this question I was using (0.32.0) and was having an issue with passing data-attributes to the button. today I tried the same thing and it works like a charm https://codesandbox.io/s/7m34vvljjq

Comment: Yeah, I found that now too. Maybe accept adamnrights's answer or @ShubhamKhatri should add their own answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOM attributes that use `data-*` will not be altered in React.

There are stricter rules around non-data attributes as of React 16, but as you can read [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html#data-and-aria-attributes), the data-attributes are left in.

With React Bootstrap, certain elements have had [issues](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1593) receiving data-attributes, if they map to say a list of

items. If you show your JSX it might make diagnosing easier.

Comment: Oh,this is actually true. It'd be cool if you add an example of JSX and rendered HTML here, but +1 this works.